# Could the stack be swapped to disk on Linux and can it be prevented

Tags: linux, swap, virtual-memory, stack

On Linux, is it possible that memory pages that contain the process stack get swapped to disk? If so, is there a way to prevent that, either at compile time or at runtime.

I'm asking because of a discussion on GitHub about [potentially leaking secrets from local variables on the stack](https://github.com/resilar/sqleet/issues/4)

In case an answer to that question not only depends on the kernel, but also depends on the userspace toolchain in use (libc, dynamic linker etc.), my question is about GNU/Linux and Android in particular.

Comment: Look up "swap encryption".

Comment: @Kusalananda: I don't have control over the target environment. At least not enough to encrypt the swap

Comment: Yes, almost all memory of a process may be swapped to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, (nearly) all of a process’s memory can be swapped out, including its heap and its stack.

However it is possible to lock pages of memory into physical RAM, so that they can not be swapped out. This is done using the [`mlock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) system call (or `mlockall` to lock all of a process’s memory). This is a privileged operation, so the process needs to have the appropriate capability, `CAP_IPC_LOCK` (see `gnome-keyring-daemon` for an example of this: `/sbin/getcap /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon`).

Comment: I knew about mlock. Since I don't know which pages contain the stack, and when a new page is allocated to back the stack, this only leaves me with mlockall (assuming that I am even allowed to lock that amount of memory, since it can be limited by the kernel).

I was really hoping that there was a way to lock only the stack.

Comment: Yeah you need to know where the stack is and how it will grow if you want to only lock the stack; AFAIK there’s no easy way to just say “lock the stack, including any new pages it needs as it grows”. Most programs wanting to lock sensitive data process it on the heap, it’s much easier that way... You could also lock the individual buffers involved once they’re allocated on the stack, before using them.

Comment: Yes, I put my sensitive data on the heap and lock it with mlock and mprotect. This is about local variables potentially ending up on the stack instead of registers.

Comment: There’s no easy fix for that unfortunately (yet...).